# programing power source over GPIB with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gpib

I'm trying to communicate with a Yokogawa GS200 DC source connected to windows PC over GPIB using c++ and Qt.

I found a library from Yokogawa (https://y-link.yokogawa.com/YL008.po?V_ope_type=Show&Download_id=DL00002096&Language_id=EN) that should do the task; however, when I tried running a simple code it compiled without errors, but the there was no output or any sign that the functions were executed. I would just get "press <ENTER> to exit this window"

I'm not sure what is wrong exactly, anyone has any ideas?

The code and header file are the following:

main:

```
#include "tmctl.h"


 int main()
        {

     char adr[100];
     int  ret;
     int  id;
     char buf[1000];
     int  length;


ret = TmcInitialize( TM_CTL_GPIB, "11", &id );

if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}

ret = TmcSetTerm( id, 3, 1 );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}


ret = TmcSetTimeout( id, 300 );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}


ret = TmcSetRen( id, 1 );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}


/* sending *RST */
ret = TmcSend( id, "*RST" );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}

/* *sending IDN? & receiving query */
ret = TmcSend( id, "*IDN?" );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}



ret = TmcReceive( id, buf, 1000, &length );
if( ret != 0 ) {
    return  TmcGetLastError( id );
}


        }
```

header:

```
    /*STARTM------------------------------------------------------------------
+       Module Name     : tmctl.h                                        +
+       Abstract        : Yokogawa T&M Remote Control functions.         +
+       Revision History:                                                +
+       Rev.    Date.          Notes.                                    +
+       --------------------------------------------------------------   +
+       2.0     20070309    USBTMC2 VXI11 supported. thread safe support +
+       2.1     20080508    RS232C expand                                +
+       2.2     20080704    Add TmcGetInitializeError.                   +
+       2.3     20121121    coped 64 bits                                +
-ENDM-------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ifndef _TMCTL_H
#define _TMCTL_H    1

#include <windows.h>

/* Control setting */
#define TM_NO_CONTROL   0
#define TM_CTL_GPIB 1
#define TM_CTL_RS232    2
#define TM_CTL_USB  3
#define TM_CTL_ETHER    4
#define TM_CTL_USBTMC   5
#define TM_CTL_ETHERUDP 6
#define TM_CTL_USBTMC2  7               // 2007/01/19 add
#define TM_CTL_VXI11    8               // 2007/01/19 add
#define TM_CTL_USB2 9

/* GPIB */

/* RS232 */
#define TM_RS_1200      '0'
#define TM_RS_2400      '1'
#define TM_RS_4800      '2'
#define TM_RS_9600      '3'
#define TM_RS_19200     '4'
#define TM_RS_38400     '5'
#define TM_RS_57600     '6'
#define TM_RS_115200            '7'         // Ver2.1

#define TM_RS_8N1       '0'
#define TM_RS_7E        '1'
#define TM_RS_7O        '2'
#define TM_RS_8O        '3'         // Ver2.1 8bit,odd,onestopbit
#define TM_RS_7N5       '4'         // Ver2.1 7bit,noparity,one5stopbit
#define TM_RS_8N2       '5'

#define TM_RS_NO        '0'
#define TM_RS_XON       '1'
#define TM_RS_HARD      '2'

/* USB */
#define TM_USB_CHECK_OK             0
#define TM_USB_CHECK_NOTOPEN                    1
#define TM_USB_CHECK_NODEVICE                   2

#define TM_USB_READPIPE             0
#define TM_USB_WRITEPIPE            1
#define TM_USB_STATUSPIPE           2

/* Error Number */
#define TMCTL_NO_ERROR              0x00000000      /* No error */
#define TMCTL_TIMEOUT               0x00000001      /* Timeout */
#define TMCTL_NO_DEVICE             0x00000002      /* Device Not Found */
#define TMCTL_FAIL_OPEN             0x00000004      /* Open Port Error */
#define TMCTL_NOT_OPEN              0x00000008      /* Device Not Open */
#define TMCTL_DEVICE_ALREADY_OPEN               0x00000010      /* Device Already Open */
#define TMCTL_NOT_CONTROL           0x00000020      /* Controller Not Found */
#define TMCTL_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER                 0x00000040      /* Parameter is illegal */
#define TMCTL_SEND_ERROR            0x00000100      /* Send Error */
#define TMCTL_RECV_ERROR            0x00000200      /* Receive Error */
#define TMCTL_NOT_BLOCK             0x00000400      /* Data is not Block Data */
#define TMCTL_SYSTEM_ERROR          0x00001000      /* System Error */
#define TMCTL_ILLEGAL_ID            0x00002000      /* Device ID is Illegal */
#define TMCTL_NOT_SUPPORTED         0x00004000      /* this feature not supportred */
#define TMCTL_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER               0x00008000      /* unsufficient buffer size */

/* L2 Error Number */
#define TMCTL2_NO_ERROR             (00000)         /* No error */
#define TMCTL2_TIMEOUT              (10001)         /* Timeout */
#define TMCTL2_NO_DEVICE            (10002)         /* Device Not Found */
#define TMCTL2_FAIL_OPEN            (10003)         /* Open Port Error */
#define TMCTL2_NOT_OPEN             (10004)         /* Device Not Open */
#define TMCTL2_DEVICE_ALREADY_OPEN              (10005)         /* Device Already Open */
#define TMCTL2_NOT_CONTROL          (10006)         /* Controller Not Found */
#define TMCTL2_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER                (10007)         /* Parameter is illegal */
#define TMCTL2_SEND_ERROR           (10008)         /* Send Error */
#define TMCTL2_RECV_ERROR           (10009)         /* Receive Error */
#define TMCTL2_NOT_BLOCK            (10010)         /* Data is not Block Data */
#define TMCTL2_SYSTEM_ERROR         (10011)         /* System Error */
#define TMCTL2_ILLEGAL_ID           (10012)         /* Device ID is Illegal */
#define TMCTL2_NOT_SUPPORTED                    (10013)         /* this feature not supportred */
#define TMCTL2_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER              (10014)         /* unsufficient buffer size */

#define ADRMAXLEN           (64)

typedef struct _Devicelist
{
    char    adr[ADRMAXLEN] ;
} DEVICELIST ;

typedef struct _DevicelistEx
{
    char        adr[ADRMAXLEN] ;
unsigned short  vendorID ;
unsigned short  productID ;
    char        dummy[188] ;
} DEVICELISTEX ;



typedef void(__stdcall *Hndlr)(int, UCHAR, ULONG, ULONG) ;

/* Functions */
#ifndef _TMCTL_DEFINES
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern  "C" {
#endif
extern  int     __stdcall TmcInitialize( int wire, char* adr, int* id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetIFC( int id, int tm ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcDeviceClear( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcDeviceTrigger( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSend( int id, char* msg ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSendByLength( int id, char* msg, int len ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSendSetup( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSendOnly( int id, char* msg, int len, int end ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceive( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveSetup( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveOnly( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveBlockHeader( int id, int* len ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveBlockData( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen, int* end ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckEnd( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetCmd( int id, char* cmd ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetRen( int id, int flag ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGetLastError( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGetDetailLastError( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckError( int id, int sts, char* msg, char* err ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetTerm( int id, int eos, int eot ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetEos( int id, unsigned char eos ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetTimeout( int id, int tmo ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetDma( int id, int flg ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGetStatusByte( int id, unsigned char* sts ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcFinish( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSearchDevices(int wire, DEVICELIST* list, int max, int* num,char* option) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSearchDevicesEx(int wire, DEVICELISTEX* list, int max, int* num,char* option) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcWaitSRQ(int id, char* stsbyte, int tout) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcAbortWaitSRQ(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSetCallback(int id,Hndlr func, ULONG p1, ULONG p2) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcResetCallback(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSendTestData(int id, char* msg, int len ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveTestData( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcInitiateAbortBulkIn(int id, UCHAR tagNo) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcInitiateAbortBulkOut(int id, UCHAR tagNo) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckAbortBulkInStatus(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckAbortBulkOutStatus(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcEncodeSerialNumber(char* encode,size_t len,char* src) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcDecodeSerialNumber(char* decode,size_t len,char* src) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGotoLocal( int id ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcLocalLockout(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcAbortPipe(int id,long pipeNo) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcResetPipe(int id,long pipeNo) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcWriteHeader(int id, int blen) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcReceiveWithoutWriteHeader(int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen, int* end ) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGetTagNo(int id, UCHAR* tag) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcSendByLength2( int id, char* msg, int msgSize, int len, CHAR eof) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcDeviceChangeNotify(HWND hWnd, BOOL bStart) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckUSB(int id) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcGetPipeNo(int id,int type,int* pipeNo) ;
extern  int     __stdcall TmcCheckGUID(void *lParam) ;
extern  ULONG   __stdcall TmcGetInitializeError() ;

// L2
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSearchDevices(int wire, DEVICELIST* adrlist, int max, int *num,char* option) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSearchDevicesEx(int wire, DEVICELISTEX* adrlist, int max, int *num,char* option) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcInitialize( int wire, char* adr, int* id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcInitializeEx( int wire, char* adr, int* id, int timeout ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcFinish( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSend( int id, char* msg ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSendByLength( int id, char* msg, int len ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSendSetup( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSendOnly( int id, char* msg, int len, int end ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcReceive( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcReceiveSetup( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcReceiveOnly( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcReceiveBlockHeader( int id, int* length ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcReceiveBlockData( int id, char* buff, int blen, int* rlen, int* end ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcCheckEnd( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcDeviceClear( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetRen( int id, int flag ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGetLastError( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetTerm( int id, int eos, int eot ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetTimeout( int id, int tmo ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcCreateSRQHandler( int id, UINT msgId, HWND hWnd) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcDleateSRQHandler( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetCallback(int id,Hndlr func, ULONG p1, ULONG p2) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcResetCallback(int id) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSet( int id, char *msg) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetBinary( int id, char* msg, char *buf, int size ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGet( int id, char *msg, char* buf, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGetBinary( int id, char *msg, char* buf, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGetErrorQueue(int id) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetNE( int id, char *msg) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetBinaryNE( int id, char* msg, char *buf, int size ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGetNE( int id, char *msg, char* buf, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcGetBinaryNE( int id, char *msg, char* buf, int blen, int* rlen ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetNES( int id, char *msg) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcSetBinaryNES( int id, char* msg, char *buf, int size ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcLock( int id ) ;
extern  int __stdcall xTmcUnlock( int id ) ;

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

#endif
```

a discription of the functions and variables in addition to the .dll file can be found in the library folder [here](https://y-link.yokogawa.com/YL008.po?V_ope_type=Show&Download_id=DL00002096&Language_id=EN).

of course I used `LIBS += "...\tmctl.dll"` to link the library to my project too.

Comment: What output were you expecting and how do you know that the functions did not execute? Did you run it under a debugger?

Comment: I was expecting the Yokogawa to send me its ID number in responce to the "*IDN?" command. Yes I did, and also I tried adding a simple fprint command within the code to see if it will actually reach it but it never got printed. all what I got was the "press ENTER to exit this window" message

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, so the code is working. I'm not sure how (it is the exact same code that I have upthere).

The only difference though is that I tried running the code using VS and for that I added the dll file to the (C\windows\system) directory. After it worked there I thought of giving it another try in Qt and surprise it worked!

Although I doubt having the dll file in the system directory has any effect because I refrenced another location when I included it in Qt.

If anyone has any insights or theories please feel free to share.

Comment: Try using Dependency Walker. It's without a doubt the best tool to troubleshoot DLL problems.